# Не работают стрелки вверх/вниз ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Вчера поставил убунту 20.04 и радовлся жизни, щас пк запустил и вижу, что при использовании fn+up звук не добавляется как прежде, хотя alt+down работает как положено, стрелки вверх и вниз также перестали работать (стрелка в право отвалилась во время написания вопроса, лол) левая вродь живая. При использовании alt+up открываются новые окна chrome, а при нажатии down какая-то пикча (на скрине). Эт что за дичь вообще, kde не ставил, в биндах клавишь лишь отключил пару комбинаций в надежде, что это что-то да даст (не дало)

Pic: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Как прежде" это когда? На другой ОС? А здесь вы настроили эти комбинации?

Comment: @dIm0n  "Как прежде"  это вчера и на другой ОС (шиндоус)

Answer (score 0):

Угадайте что помогло, ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКА, опыт работы в этой осью, кажись, будет не забываем ;)